# Can't boot Ubuntu after setting up partitions manually during installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

My HDD is approximately 160 GB.

I've created 4 partitions:

- the `/` one (~25000 MB)
- the `/boot` one, which is about 1 GB
- the `swap` (another 2 GB)
- a 50000 MB `/home` partition.

Now, on the `Device for boot loader installation` option, I selected the boot partition (I did so because I am going to dual boot ubuntu with another distro, tell me if something changes). And that's it.
The installation ends successfully, so I restart the computer. And the BIOS tells me there's no OS in the system!

I insert the DVD again, and in the partition scheme, it says that Ubuntu is installed. Where have I failed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the boot loader on the hard disk device (`/sda`) and not on the boot partition. So select your hard disk device for "Device for boot loader installation".

Answer (score 3):

My first suspicion would be that the boot loader isn't where it should be. Note that it needs to match what device your BIOS is set to boot. If that is still the disk or stick you used to install Ubuntu....

You can also boot in to a live instance, perhaps the same one used to install, to take a look around and figure out what happened and maybe re-install your boot loader.